# node.js multiple app.param()

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I was trying to use two different app.param for different paramaters but it dosnt seem to be possible.  when the server checks for the first paramater i get it to sequencially check the second paramater and even if it is checking the second paramater in the second app.param, it nullifies the first paramater from working.

```
app.param('chatroom', function(req, res, next, chatroom) {
    Chatroom.findOne({ 'chat.roomname' : chatroom }, function(err, chatroom) {
        if(err)
            throw err;
        if(!chatroom) 
            return next();
        req.chatroom = chatroom;
        next();
    });
});

app.get('/:chatroom', function(req, res) {
    Profile.findOne({ 'pic.username' : req.user.local.username}, function(err, profilepic) {
    if(err)
        throw err;
    res.render('pages/chatroom', {
        chatroom : req.chatroom,
        profilepic : profilepic,
        user : req.user
    });
    });
});

app.param('username', function(req, res, next, username) {
    User.findOne({ 'local.username' : username }, function(err, user) {
        if(err)
            throw err;
        if(!user){
            return res.sendStatus(404);
        }
        req. profile = user;
    next();
    });
});



app.get('/:username', function(req, res) {
    async.parallel([
        function(callback) {
            Profile.findOne({ 'pic.username' : req. profile.local.username }, function(err, profilepic) {

                if(err) 
                    throw err;

                callback(null, profilepic);
            });
        }, function(callback) {

            Buddy.find({ 'bud.username' : req. profile.local.username }, function(err, buddy) {

                if(err)
                    throw err;

                callback(null, buddy);
            });
        }, function(callback) {

            Buddy.count({ 'bud.username' : req. profile.local.username}, function(err, buddycount) {

                if(err)
                    throw err;

                callback(null, buddycount);
            });
        }, function(callback){

            Userpost.find({ 'post.postuser' : req. profile.local.username }).sort({ 'post.date' : 1 }).exec(function(err, userpost) {

                if(err)
                    throw err;

                callback(null, userpost);
            });
        }, function(callback) {

            Userpost.count({ 'post.postuser' : req. profile.local.username }, function(err,postcount) {

                if(err)
                    throw err;

                callback(null, postcount);
            });
        }], function(err, results){

                if(err)
                    throw err;

                var profilepic = results[0];
                var buddy = results[1];
                var buddycount = results[2];
                var userpost = results[3];
                var postcount = results[4];



                res.render('pages/visitprofile', {
                    user : req. profile,
                    profilepic : profilepic,
                    buddy : buddy,
                    buddycount : buddycount,
                    userpost : userpost,
                    postcount : postcount
                });
            }
            );  
});
```

So is there I way i can get both parameters to work on the server at the same time.  I reorder them and one works with the other one not working.  Maybe i can make next() function skip over the other parameter some how?

Comment: Thats the problem, either way it is going to the next part which is the other app.param.  Is there a way to skip the app.param and the app.get('/:chatroom') with the next() function?

Comment: The `app.get('/:chatroom', ...` and `app.get('/:username'` ones don't have a `next`?

Comment: Yeah i got it.  just did if statement if(req. profile) return next(); on the following routes